# Свободная камера

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужна свободная камера для юнити на языке C#, но чтобы камера была зафиксирована за объектом. Те можно вращать ее и немного отдалять. Она так же называется камерой от 3 лица. Её можно отдалять от объекта и вращать вокруг него.

Comment: Вам стоить посмотреть на этот экземпляр.
[Камера ...](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwiO7Le8t-zwAhUHThgKHS4FCCkYABAEGgJsZQ&ae=2&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAESQOD2RETfmmydYJzlXHFt73HdAq16atVASkHJsxJG3UGQv8QH4V09fiYlstxew04vANMJYSHSfWJutnlFyKDi25Y&sig=AOD64_28QjlmQTw2m2iLa5YwWav2y07gpg&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjh_668t-zwAhWtw4sKHYbFCHAQ9aACegQIARBL&adurl=)

Comment: Базовый алгоритм такой камеры прост: при старте камеры определяете её расстояние путем вычитания из её позиции позиции объекта (`offset`). Далее перед отрисовкой кадра нужно изменить позицию на сумму `offset` и позиции объекта. Для вращения камеры алгоритм аналогичный.

Comment: Будет выглядеть это как-то так: https://pastebin.com/520UJcyu

Answer (score 0):

Точный скрипт не дам, но в инете есть множество примеров. Вот, например:
https://coderlessons.com/articles/mobilnaia-razrabotka-articles/unity3d-kamery-ot-tretego-litsa
Да и вроде бы в Standard Assets был пример контроллера персонажа от третьего лица.
А в общих чертах суть такова: нужно создать камеру за игроком и прописать ей следование за игроком и взаимодействие с мышкой.